# How to apply onChange event for a heapbox using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Suppose

```
<select class="csrSelect" id="queueSelect">
    <option value="">Select Another Queue to Manage</option>
    <option value="1">Store 1</option>
    <option value="2">Store 2</option>
    <option value="3">Store 3</option>
    <option value="4">Store 4</option>
    <option value="5">Store 5</option>
    <option value="6">Store 6</option>
</select>
```

and the css class 'csrSelect' has implemented heapbox on this select box. Now i want to call an onChange event like:

```
<select class="csrSelect" id="queueSelect" onChange="Changed()">
    <option value="">Select Another Queue to Manage</option>
    <option value="1">Store 1</option>
    <option value="2">Store 2</option>
    <option value="3">Store 3</option>
    <option value="4">Store 4</option>
    <option value="5">Store 5</option>
    <option value="6">Store 6</option>
</select>
```

But it is not working.Please Help me.

Comment: try with diff function name

Comment: Please provide your javascript as well. And jsfiddle would be great.

Comment: why `$('#queueSelect"').on('change',fn..)` wont work ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: i already did that..this is working fine for normal drop down box but not for a heap box.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use heapbox events.You should use heapbox onchange event in your purpose.

```
$(".mySelect").heapbox({
'onChange':function(){},
'openStart':function(){},
'openComplete':function(){},
'closeStart':function(){},
'closeComplete':function(){},
});
```

You can read documentation from http://www.bartos.me/heapbox/
Its working perfect..
Enjoy...

Answer (score 0):

You can setup heapbox to trigger events of original elements this way:

```
$('select').heapbox({
   "onChange":function(val, elm) {
       elm.trigger('change');
    }
});
```